# Lazy translate in Django

Tags: python, django, translate

Have a trouble with a lazy translate in Django. In my settings.py, i use construction as:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
TASK_REPEAT_KEYS = (_('never'), _('daily'), _('weekly'), _('monthly'),)
TASK_REPEAT = dict(zip(TASK_REPEAT_KEYS, range(1, len(TASK_REPEAT_KEYS) + 1)))
```

and get error:

> django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: The translation
>   infrastructure cannot be initialized before the apps registry is
>   ready.

Who faced a similar problem?

Comment: Can I ask why you need to translate these settings? Normally you should only be translating things that the end user will see

Comment: I tried copying your lines to one of my projects and got a "SECRET_KEY cannot be empty" error. Then I moved the lines towards the end of the file, after the SECRET_KEY is set, and it worked normally. I have no idea why, but you could try moving the lines to the end of the settings file and see if that changes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is occurring because the `dict()` call is trying to evaluate the translate. This negates any lazy translate you were attempting to use. What you could do instead is use a function that has some simple caching built into it to return that list without reevaluating that dictionary every time.